# Find Rows that DO NOT meet criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Im trying to validate a new nightly procedure that updates engagement scores. I have a list of 461 ID #s that came back from the validation....In the query below to confirm the info coming back is correct, I found 233 out of 461 that meet the criteria using the code below. My problem is finding the rows that DO NOT meed the criteria. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP_TABLE w

JOIN entity e ON e.id_number = w.id_number
        AND e.id_number IN (‘ ID NUMBERS IN QUESTION PUT HERE ‘)

JOIN xcomment c ON c.id_number = e.id_number
           AND c.comment_code = 'ES'

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM activity a 
       WHERE a.id_number = e.id_number
       AND to_char(a.date_added, 'YYYYMMDD') >= '20180101'
       AND to_char(a.date_added, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20180307')
```

Comment: What happens when you use NOT EXISTS instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP_TABLE w

JOIN entity e ON e.id_number = w.id_number
        AND e.id_number IN (‘ ID NUMBERS IN QUESTION PUT HERE ‘)

JOIN xcomment c ON c.id_number = e.id_number
           AND c.comment_code = 'ES'

WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM activity a 
       WHERE a.id_number = e.id_number
       AND to_char(a.date_added, 'YYYYMMDD') >= '20180101'
       AND to_char(a.date_added, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20180307')
```

Comment: Oh my lord of course. Sorry to waste every one's time! I'd up-vote but not yet at 15 rep. Thanks again!